# What’s the difference between solipsistic and narcissistic?

Tags: word-usage, comparisons

From my understanding, both *solipsistic* and *narcissistic* refer to self-absorption but in different ways. Could someone please explain the difference? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

'Solipsism' has roots in philosophy (theory that the self is all that can be known to exist). By extension, it came to mean general 'selfishness'.

'Narcissism' comes from the Greek myth of a Narcissus who fell in love with his reflection in the mirror (hence, focus on appearance) and is now associated with psychology (think: sense of entitlement, lack of empathy, need for admiration, underlying low self-esteem)

See: 
https://www.lexico.com/definition/solipsism

https://www.lexico.com/definition/narcissism

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_personality_disorder